# How can I use a combo box that displays data from one table and add it to another using MS Access?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, combobox

I am developing a database system. It is for a canoe club. The part of the database I am stuck on is assigning a member of the canoe club to a canoe qualification course when/if they undertake one.

Here is a stripped down view of my tables:

```
members
-------------------------------------
| memberID | first_name | last_name |
-------------------------------------
| 1        | John       | Jacobs    |
| 2        | Ellie      | Graham    |
| 3        | Paul       | Abbot     |
-------------------------------------

course_info
---------------------------------------
| courseID | course_name | Instructor |
---------------------------------------
| 1        | BCU Level 1 | Ryan Adams |
| 2        | BCU Level 2 | Ryan Adams |
| 3        | BCU Level 3 | Ryan Adams |
| 4        | BCU Level 4 | Ryan Adams |
| 5        | BCU Level 5 | Ryan Adams |
---------------------------------------

course_progress
-------------------------------
| memberID | courseID | grade |
-------------------------------
| 1        | 2        | 4     |
| 1        | 4        | 5     |
| 2        | 1        | 3     |
| 3        | 5        | 2     |
-------------------------------
```

So as you can see,`course_progress` displays the courses a member has undertaken as well as their grade by using `memberID` and `courseID`.

Firstly is that the correct (or a correct) way of doing this? If so, here is my problem...

Using Access I want to create a form that allows me to assign a member to a course. So I have a combo box that lists all of the members and another that lists all of the courses. As well as a box for inputting the grade.

When I fill in this form it only adds the grade to the `course_progress` table. I feel as though this is the case because I am using fields from different tables in the combo box. The other solution that while works is less than ideal is to have `memberID` and `courseID` in the combo box. I believe that works as I am using fields from the table I am trying to add to. However it is not user friendly as ID's are meaningless to a user.

So I want to be able to select the member name and course name from the combo box and add them to the `course_progress` table as well as the grade.

Any guidance would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you created comboboxes correctly? Check Column Count and Column Widths properties first, ID column normally should be first column, and column width for first column should be 0, in this case user won't see IDs, only names and after selecting the data from combobox in "New" record the data with ID will be added normally

Comment: @SergeyS.I have changed the widths of the columns so that the ID is visible and even selecting that does not work. The grade and dates (I didn't include dates in my example above but they are there) get entered correctly but the courseID and memberID get entered as 0 regardless of what I enter.

Comment: Didn't understand about dates. How do you enter date? One combobox can update one field. Please give us content of Row Source of both comboboxes along with Control Source and Bound Column. It's simple: Row Source returns set of rows and columns, content of column, which # is in in Bound Column property stored in Control Source

Comment: In your case for instance for members combobox properties should be:

        Control Source: memberID
        Row Source: SELECT members.memberID, members.first_name, members.last_name FROM members; 
        Bound Column: 1
        Column Count: 3
        Column Width: 0";1";1"

Comment: Please check the [base information](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Create-a-list-of-choices-by-using-a-list-box-or-combo-box-70abf4a9-0439-4885-9099-b9fa83517603) about comboboxes, it may be useful

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, is your form bound to the course_progress table., and are the two combo boxes bound to the memberID and courseID fields of the progress table.

Secondly, what have you used as the query for each combo box.  You should be querying the members table.  Assuming you do, you will have 3 columns, the first being the member ID and that should be the "bound column" in the combo box properties.  in the format section you will need to give column widths, and I would give the memberID column a width of 0 so it doesn't show.  But you should say you want to display 3 columns (so you get firstname and last name in the combo box.

Do the same for the course combo box.

Comment: I have the boxes displaying the data correctly however when I use the form it enters the courseId and memberID in as 0 regardless of what I input. The other fields work as they should (grade, start_date, end_date).